# How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can see using the ratio test that this series converges, but do not know how to find the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Remember

$$ \mathrm{exp}(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{ x^n }{n!} $$

for all $x$

Thus,

$$ \sum \frac{ (\log log 2)^n }{n!} = \log 2 $$

Comment: God, yes. Can't believe didn't see that, thanks!